# How to get raw type from reflect slice

Tags: go, reflection

I want to check table reference field exist, that take the struct to ormer query table. The VaildData function take diffrent struct or slice and beego `orm.NewOrm().Read(v)` of v that only vaild pointer struct.

```golang
func VaildData(cols ...interface{}) (err error) {
    for _, col := range cols {
        value := reflect.ValueOf(col)
        switch reflect.TypeOf(col).Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice:
            if length := value.Len(); length > 0 {
                for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
                    logs.Info("slice is %v", value.Index(i).Elem().Type().Name())
                    t := value.Index(i).Elem().Type()
                    a := value.Index(i).Interface().(t)
                    err = Ormer().Read(a)
                    if err != nil {
                        return err
                    }
                }
            }
        case reflect.Ptr:
            logs.Info(value)
            t := value.Interface().Type()
            err = Ormer().Read(value.Interface().(t))
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        default:
            return fmt.Errorf("invalid collection type, need pointer or slice pointer %s", reflect.ValueOf(col))
        }


    }
    return nil
}
```

```golang
type Cluster struct {
    ID int
    Name string
    Environments []*Environment
    Region *Region
}

type Environment struct {
    ID int
    Name string
}

type Region struct {
   ID int
   Name string
}

c := Cluster{}
err := VaildData(c.Environments, c.Region)
```

but that does not work, it excpet error.

```
t is not a type
```

Comment: Type assertion only works with types, and `t` is not a type, it is a `reflect.Type`. What is the signature of the `Read` function?

Comment: The Read is beego orm,  `func(md interface{}, cols ...string) error`, it only vaild pointer struct, so Read(value.Index(i).Interface()) will except `Handler crashed with error <Ormer> table: '`.`' not found, make sure it was registered  `

Comment: `value.Index(i).Interface()` is the underlying value.  Does `Ormer().Read()` expect the first argument to be a `reflect.Value` or an unwrapped value?  A `reflect.Value` is used in the ptr case, but it looks like the application is attempting to use the unwrapped value for slice elements.

Comment: the use case like this ` Ormer() :=  orm.NewOrm();   e := new(Enviroment);  e.Name = prod; err := Ormer().Read(e)`  doucument is here https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/object.md#read

Comment: A reflect.Value is used in the ptr case, this is my mistake, sorry, I change it